# Failing to parse json from response on Android but works on iOS React Native

Tags: react-native, fetch, expo

I'm using React Native fetch to retrieve a resource on amazon S3. The response is OK on both android and iOS but a hit a wall when calling res.json() for Android. I've debug some as of now but haven't had the time yet to dig deeper. Calling out here, since I'm short on time, to see if someone knows what's happening.

What I've noticed so far is that when a log the length of res.text() it differs with 1 between the response on iOS device and Android, Android having +1 in content. I've been able to get a hold on the actual file that I'm fetching server side, so I did a test with json-fixer in a node script, it says it fails because it encountered unexpected "".

I've read some things here that fetch for RN adds charset UTF-8 for Android but not iOS. But could that be the case here? And in what way if so...? The server respond with application/json as mediatype, nothing else.

So, my questions is; why would the content served differ between iOS and Android for React Native? The iOS handles parsing the text representation of the JSON fine, whereas the Android fails, due to some unexpected char somewhere ("" if you believe json-fixers' error) what it seems like.

Using

```
Expo SDK 35, React Native 0.59.
Using iOS simulator which works
Using Android physical device via LAN to expo server
```

Thanks in advance to anyone having a tip on whats up here!

Solved. Turns out that fetch on android device (okhttp in native code I think) appended a " " for some reason. By calling res.text() and then parse that string after s.trim() did the trick.

Comment: Have you tried, `JSON.parse(res)`?

Comment: Hi Jetzon, I think it's appropriate to write your solution as an answer below and accept it. Your solution fixed my bug btw.