# API Response returns Mappable Object in iOS but Json on Android

Tags: json, reactjs, react-native, api, mobile

I'm a newbie on mobile development and React-Native, this might come across as a very mundane thing to some of you, but I'm making an Api call and then mapping the results to create the same component but with different data.

This works fine on Iphone but on Android it does not.

The response from the req is an Object for both devices but on Android, it seems to be a json object that I simply cannot map with or use on a Flatlist.

I've tried JSON.parse to get the json object to a js object but it simply doesn't, like it. It throws out an unexpected token error.

I've attached a log for the Android object first and the same object for iPhone (Already mappable and a JS object).

Can someone tell me why this happens? I'd very much appreciate it!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NOkG.png)

____________________ After Changing to Fetch _______________________

Hey, I changed from Axios to fetch and now I get an unhandled promise warning saying 'Unhandled promise rejection: SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '' '.

Don't think I'm doing anything wrong here...

[image: Fetch Code]

Comment: are u using `axios` ? ,,, This `unexpected token` error fire on emulator and real-device ?

Comment: Yes I'm using axios and it's on a real device with the Expo Metro Server.

Comment: If i try to map through the Json response on Android I ill get "Error undefined is not an object React Native", but on Iphone it will just work

Comment: If you could open **debugger on your device** and see your response obj ... if it's truncated ... then `fetch` is your way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Well ... your response-object **gets truncated** due to memory issues on your real-device ... most likely your **response object** is kinda large ...

And that's just the way `axios` fetch response-data ... through chunks, you just get a slice of the response...

I came across this issue before ... and the solution was to switch to `fetch`

**Edit**

```
try {
    const rawResponse = await fetch(...);
    const text = await rawResponse.text();
    console.log(text);
    
    const parsedRes = JSON.parse(text);
    console.log('parsedRes', parsedRes);
  } catch(error) {
    console.log('fetch error', error);
  }
```

Comment: Hey @Hend, I'm not sure that did the trick! I added some pics to the previous post to see if you can think of anything!

Comment: And you're testing (in both android and iOS) using same response-obj ... I mean same endpoint with same params? ... and Do you get valid reponse when testing using postman?

Comment: Yep, get a valid response in postman and I'm able to render the flatlist components with that same data on iOS. The Android device is the only one giving me hard time. Now with fetch, I am getting '[native code]:null in parse'

Comment: The fetch works and now have a json object but I cannot turn it into a regular js object to map through it. If I try doing json.parse(res) I get ' JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token '''

Comment: Sounds like data returned by server is not valid-json ... plz check out the edit and see if it works ...

Comment: Solved! Found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59000260/failing-to-parse-json-from-response-on-android-but-works-on-ios-react-native

Comment: Great! ... but the `.trim()` step is unnecessary ...